# junit and easymock, exception while saving

Tags: easymock

I am using EasyMock and JUnit. i am getting exception while saving. Please find below code.

EasyMock.expect(someDao.save(pojo)).andReturn(pojo);//pojo i have created with values
EasyMock.replay(someDao);

Pojo savedObject = someService.save(pojo);

but the **someService.save(pojo)** calls one more service before saving. so how can mock that service?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

The same way:

```
SomeDao someDao = createMock(SomeDao.class);
SomeOtherDao someOtherDao = createMock(SomeOtherDao.class);
someService.setSomeDao(someDao);
someService.setSomeOtherDao(someOtherDao);
EasyMock.expect(someOtherDao.save(pojo)).andReturn(pojo);
EasyMock.expect(someDao.save(pojo)).andReturn(pojo);
EasyMock.replay(someOtherDao, someDao);

Pojo savedObject = someService.save(pojo);
```